# Setting up Network File System on Windows XP 64 Bit machine

Tags: windows, 64-bit

> Microsoft's SFU is not supported for
>   64-bit XP OS. Read here -
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920751

I want to set up a NFS Client on 64-bit Windows XP. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin does not support NFS CLient. Is it possible to reverse engineer the msi and just extract out the required files to be set up. I fee the entire suite as a whole does not install on 64-Bit windows XP , rather if I want to individually want to install NFS Client only, that should be possible.

Any thoughts on this ?